# Error Laravel 5.4 upload .docs as .bin

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

Im making a Resource Documents to upload files in my server, and it works fine most of the time, I can upload images and pdfs without problems, but when trying to upload a .doc or .docx It gets uploaded as a .bin file. I dont  know why.

Here's were I upload the file in the controller

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    $extension = $request->file('document')->guessClientExtension();

    //the store method returns a path to the file, 
    $path = $request->file('document')->store('public/documents');
    $name = $request->input('name');
    echo($extension);die;
```

when echoing the extension it says "bin" and the file is in fact stored as .bin but the file is a .doc

I can upload pdfs and .jpgs without problems using the same function, I hope you guys can help me

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still facing this problem, just need to take an original extension and file name this way:

```
// we need original extension in case we change our filename
$extension = $request->resume->getClientOriginalExtension();
$filename = $request->resume->getClientOriginalName();

// and use `storeAs` method in this case and give filename as a second parameter
$request->file('document')->storeAs('public/documents', $filename);
```

> In case of some mime types Laravel fails to get the correct file extension, so we have to remind it what the original extension is.